# JS get request to external URL

Tags: javascript, get, request

I would like to make a request to an external URL and work with the content of this URL. The content of the URL contains plain text, but it has around 50,000 characters.

So I did search a little bit and find keywords like: Ajax request, get request, Async / sync, callback etc.

But all of these solutions are complicated.

How could be an easy example, with this criteria:

- Example URL: http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=wbSwFU6tY1c
- The request should be **only in Javascript**. It should be an **async** request and with the **callback** function.

Thank you.

---

#### **Update:**

Please note, the example URL changed to a new one.

When I run a GET request (for example with this [Online GET request tool](https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx)), than I am able to read the response content. It's not like downloading anything before, just displaying the content. And this is exactly what I want to do. Just write the 'response content' of this URL to a variable in JS and work with it later.

Comment: "But all of these solutions are complicated."  Are they?  Why not ask a question about what you're confused about.  There are only two APIs you can use to make an HTTP request from JavaScript in-browser.  AJAX and the Fetch API.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt", true);
request.onload = () => {console.log(request.responseText)}
request.send();
```

Take a look at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. But does your example include the criterias of 'async' and 'callback' while doing the GET request?

Comment: do you see the third parameter for `open()`? That’s a `async=true` value. Lastly, the request.onload sets a function which will `console.log` the contents of your request when it comes back at some point in time, aka, a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

```js
fetch('https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/shakira/waka-waka')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Works fine with this URL. Please note, that I have updated my example URL. The new URL is more similar to the real URL. With the new URL there is an Error fetch :-S....

Comment: actually, updated url is directly downloading the data on hitting from the browser, can you please share the url documentation source.

Comment: well, I didn't find any documentation regarding this. The question is, how the solution looks like, in case of such a URL. What I wonder is, if you make a GET request (for example with this URL https://www.httpdebugger.com/tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx), than you are able to the see the response content. It's not like downloading anything before, just displaying the content. And this is exactly what I want to do. Just wrtie the response content to a variable in JS and work with it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/), lighter than jQuery and more compatible than other solutions. You can also find some example